# create aggregates inside a subselect without having to add referenced fields to the group by list

Tags: sql, group-by, h2

I want to do a nested grouping/aggregation of my data, but I want the flatten the output such that I only get the rows that the outer group would generate

this is how a 2 level nested group output normally looks:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|outer_group|inner_group|aggregate_value|
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|          8|dist_yes   |          191.0|
|          8|dist_no    |           83.0|
|          9|dist_yes   |          135.0|
|          9|dist_no    |           89.0|
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

but what I want would be three columns, first one for the outer group, second one called "dist_no", for the aggregate for "dist_no", third one called "dist_yes", for the aggregate for "dist_yes"

there would be two rows, outer_group vals would be 8, 9, dist_no vals would be 83, 89, dist_yes vals would be 191, 135

I've tried using subqueries in the select statement, and taking the dist_yes_no field out of the group by list, but the subqueries need to reference the dist_yes_no field, which means it has to be in the group by list (at least with H2, which I'm using) and I'm back where I started

thoughts? thanks

Comment: Could you show sample data and the expected output?  That's commonly easier to follow than a description of what you're after.

Comment: this should be doable with window functions (I think IBM calls them "olap" functions)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
    select a.outer_group, a.aggr_dist_no, b.aggr_dist_yes from
    (select outer_group, 
sum(value) as aggr_dist_no, 
null as aggr_dist_yes 
where inner_group = dist_no 
group by outer_group) a
    join
    (select outer_group, 
null as aggr_dist_no, 
sum(value) as aggr_dist_yes
where inner_group = dist_yes 
group by outer_group) b
    on a.outer_group = b.outer_group
```